# Understanding bash signal handling

Tags: bash, exception, audio, signals, bash-trap

### Foreword

My initial intention was to write a script that keeps checking every 1 second what hardware (maybe *sink* is a better term?) is playing Spotify music (headphones, stereo,...) such that this information **is reliable even after Spotify is terminated** (as in, *this is the id of the hardware Spotify was using when it got closed*).

The script I initially wrote to do this, was essentially a script that calls and parses `pactl list` in `while true` loop to retrieve the #id of the hardware on which Spotify is playing audio.

This worked as long as Spotify was up, but when Spotify was closed, the final outcome of that "listener" was an empty string, which would seem ok to me if `pactl info` was called **after** closing Spotify, but I thought I was calling it this **before**.

At this point, I think I might have misunderstood how signal handling and `trap`s work in `bash`.

### The M(non)WE

In order to give to myself and to you a MWE, I came up with the following.

- A `driver.sh` script which launches a `listener.sh` script in background and then starts Spotify **not in background** (my understanding is that doing so, sending a signal to Spotify, e.g. closing it, results in that signla being sent to `driver.sh`); it also sets `trap` which terminates the background process.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill -TERM $bg_pid' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
./listen.sh &
bg_pid=$!
echo "bg_pid: $bg_pid"
/usr/bin/spotify
```

- A `listener.sh` script which parses `pactl list`'s output for the line `media.name` infinitely in a `while true` loop; the `trap` ensures that the parsing happens one last time upon termination.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo trap:; func; exit' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
func() {
  echo func: $(pactl list | sed -E '/media\.name/p;d')
}
while true; do
  func
  sleep 1
done
```

I thought that, given this setting, exectuting `driver.sh` from terminal would result in the following.

- Spotify opening up, and the terminal being filled, second by second with lines of the form

```
func: media.name = "Spotify"
func: media.name = "Spotify"
func: media.name = "Spotify"
...
```

- Upon closing Spotify (by killing `driver.sh` or closing Spotify window) two more line:

```
trap:
func: media.name = "Spotify"
```

Instead, what I get if I close Spotify is

```
...
func: media.name = "Spotify"
func: media.name = "Spotify"
+enrico:~$ trap:
func: # empty!
trap:
func: # why again?
```

If instead I <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> `driver.sh` I get this (comments are mine):

```
...
func: media.name = "Spotify"
func: media.name = "Spotify"
^Cfunc: media.name = "Spotify"   # here I hit ctrl+c
func: media.name = "Spotify"     # maybe this delay is because of sleep in listener.sh?
./spot.sh: line 6:  8704 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /usr/bin/spotify # why this SegV?
+enrico:~$ trap:
func: # empty!
trap:
func: # why again?
```

This is puzzling me. I thought that upon receiving the termination signal, `driver.sh` should capture it with the `trap` and run the `kill -TERM $bg_pid` command to handle it. In turn, `listener.sh`, upon receiving the signal, should execute `echo`, then `func`, then `exit`.  Only at this point should Spotify terminate. If calling `pactl list` after this would have no Spotify in it, I would understand.

Apparently I have possibly misunderstood the whole thing.

Comment: Spotify receives SIGINT the moment you hit Ctrl-C, then driver.sh traps it and kills listener.sh. What made you think that *Only at this point should Spotify terminate*?

Comment: My lack of knowledge of this topic, I guess. However this would explain why the behavior is how it is when I close Spotify (thus sending the signal to **it**). But if I hit ctrl-c in the terminal where `driver.sh` is running... how can **it** terminate before handling the exception with the code?

Comment: Understanding how bash runs commands might help. When `/usr/bin/spotify` line is run, 1) bash forks, 2) child process execs spotify, 3) bash blocks signals and starts waiting for child to die. When you hit Ctrl-C, 1) it kills child, 2) bash sees this and unblocks signals, 3) bash receives INT, takes action.

Comment: Is this because I am **not** executing `/usr/bin/spotify` in background? I mean, if I change the line to `/usr/bin/spotify &`, should this make `driver.sh` available for receiving a signal and dealing with it instead (and possibly send a term signal to `/usr/bin/spotify` as well)?

Comment: `spotify` is a child process of `driver.sh` process. When you close or send SIGINT to `spotify` process, it dies which is indepedent of the signal handling in its parent process `driver.sh`. What you're trying to do is insert a signal handler into `spotify` (so that you could do something before it dies) from its parent process - this isn't possible.

Comment: @oguzismail As I understand, OP wants to run `pactl list` to get the media name *before* `spotify` exits. When `spotify` does, you'd get a SIGCHLD regardless but that's not useful for this purpose.

Comment: @oguzismail, there was an answer from you, yesterday, which I had no time to check. Have you removed it?

Comment: @Enrico undeleted now, check it out and let me know

Comment: @oguzismail , at the moment I can't, but I'll do it this evening and let you know.

Comment: Okay. Btw, preventing spotify from segfaulting is impossible here, it's caused by an error in its design

Comment: After understanding this topic a bit more thanks to this comment and the answer, I realize that my initial intention was indeed the one @usr identified: inserting a signal handler into spotify. Now I understand why this is impossible. Thank both of you, I'm going to accept the answer since it truly illustrates the best I can do: inserting a signal handler into a wrapper around spotify. In order for this to work, I have to close spotify through the wrapper, as if I close spotify directly, the wrapper would take action when it's too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/spotify` receives SIGINT and dies before `driver.sh` terminates `listen.sh`, thus the empty output from `pactl`. You should run `/usr/bin/spotify` at the background and terminate it after terminating `listen.sh`.

So, your scripts should look like:

**driver.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill -TERM $bg_pid $!' SIGINT SIGTERM
./listen.sh &
bg_pid=$!
echo "bg_pid: $bg_pid"
/usr/bin/spotify &
wait
```

**listen.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo trap:; func; exit' SIGINT SIGTERM
func() {
  echo func: $(pactl list | sed -E '/media\.name/p;d')
}
while true; do
  func
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thank you for both answers and comments, which both helped me understand. Only pity, you deleted a comment with a nice link which someone alse could have benefited from. I myself, will have to dig in my browser history to pick that link up.

Comment: @Enrico [here is the link](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/364.html), irrelevant to the question though

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but possibly useful to the interest reader. I mean, my question tries to pinpoint a specific usecase of signal handling (am maybe it doesn't, based on the -1 and on the vote for closing it), but a reader could end up here with a wider interest in signal handling.

Comment: @Enrico okay then I'll leave it there. Wrt the downvote&closure, this question could have been way shorter&clearer without spotify and pactl; and would have received far better answers. Maybe that's the reason

Comment: I agree in hindsight.